# What is the fastest way to merge dicts with same specific keys and values in two lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Suppose I have two list of dicts:

```
dict_list1 = [{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key1': 'value1'}, 
              {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key3': 'value3'}]
dict_list2 = [{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 
              {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key4': 'value4'}]
```

I want to merge them so that dictionaries with the same `'id'` and `'sub_id'` merges, becoming like this:

```
final_list=[{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
           {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]
```

Right now I'm doing like this:

```
final_list = []
    for dict1 in dict_list1:
        for dict2 in dict_list2:
            if attrs['id'] == seats['id'] and \
                    attrs['sub_id'] == seats['sub_id']:
                final_list.append({**dict1, **dict2})
                break
```

But it looks really bad. Is there a better/faster way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) here. Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to chain both the dict lists or you just do `final=dict1+dict2` but I prefer using `chain`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain
dict_list1 = [{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key1': 'value1'}, 
              {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key3': 'value3'}]
dict_list2 = [{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key2': 'value2'}, 
              {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key4': 'value4'}]

final=chain(dict_list1,dict_list2) #You can just do final=dict_list1+dict_list2

out=defaultdict(dict)
for d in final:
    k=(d['id'],d['sub_id'])
    out[k].update(d)

list(out.values())
# [{'id': 'id1', 'sub_id': 'sub_id1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'},
#  {'id': 'id2', 'sub_id': 'sub_id2', 'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]
```

Comment: @MioMio Glad, it was useful. If it helped please accept this as answer and upvote. ;)